# Cannot create a table for some fields comes from a database on tcpdf PDF

Tags: php, laravel, tcpdf

How can we get the below custom fields to show up in a table in PDF?
We are using TCPDF library https://tcpdf.org

```
foreach ($pdf_custom_fields as $field) {
    $value = get_custom_field_value($estimate->id, $field['id'], 'estimate');
    if ($value == '') {
        continue;
    }
    
    $organization_info .= $field['name'] . ':' . $value . '<br />';
}
```

We tried the below code but it give us a fetal error

````
    $value = get_custom_field_value($estimate->id, $field['id'], 'estimate');
    if ($value == '') {
        continue;
    }
    <table style="width:100%">
    $organization_info .= <th><td>$field['name'] .</th>  <td>. $value .</td> </tr>'<br />';
</table>
} ```
````

Answer (score 1):

To present custom fields in a tabular format using TCPDF, you must create the HTML markup for the table structure and fill it with the corresponding custom field values.

```
// Initialize the table
$tableHTML = '<table style="width:100%">';

foreach ($pdf_custom_fields as $field) {
    $value = get_custom_field_value($estimate->id, $field['id'], 'estimate');
    if ($value == '') {
        continue;
    }

    $tableHTML .= '<tr>';
    $tableHTML .= '<th>' . $field['name'] . '</th>';
    $tableHTML .= '<td>' . $value . '</td>';
    $tableHTML .= '</tr>';
}

// Close the table
$tableHTML .= '</table>';

// Add the table to $organization_info
$organization_info .= $tableHTML;
```

Comment: yes, it works but cell tables are not placed side by side. is there a way to place them side by side?